# OpenGL Optimization, glBindBuffer() and glBufferData() vs creating new VBO?

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization

I have a class that makes textures in OpenGL 4.3.

So my question is...

1. Would it be faster if I render by changing one vertex buffer's vertices for each texture?

OR

2. Would it be faster if I have a vertex buffer for every texture that contains its own vertices?

I know the 1st method would require glBindBuffer() and glBufferData() every frame which sounds bad?
2nd method would mean I would call glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData once then only call glBindBuffer every frame. Although the 2nd method sounds good I want to hear other opinions.

Some context:
Creating 2d game engine that can use images and draw pixels quickly on textures or primitives using two different shaders.

Comment: So you are using this class not only to store the data for the texture itself, but also for a quad to draw the texture onto the screen? If that is the case, you should only need ONE vbo ever. Unless I mis-understand something. The question wasn't very clear.

Comment: However, if it's between only option one and two, definitely two. You are right about it being the better one.